# No text area should be selected in jQuery

Tags: jquery, select, onclick, textarea, onfocus

I have a form, and I want that the first text area would not be selected. No textarea should be selected first. I want the user to click on the textarea on their own in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute something like this:

```
jQuery("textarea").blur();
```

It makes all textareas on your page lose focus.

UPDATE:

You're using text inputs too, so add:

```
jQuery("input[type=text]").blur();
```

So add this to a script file/script tag in the head of your page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("textarea").blur();
    jQuery("input[type=text]").blur();
});
```

Comment: Okay il be honest, im not good at this. Can you please visit this site, http://www.vulcansfurnace.com/stronglands/lands-for-sale/ then click inquire now then thats the form im working on.

Comment: I want no text area to be selected on form load.

Comment: You're welcome :) Please accept this answer by clicking the 'V' on the left if this answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('textarea').blur();
```

This will trigger the `blur` event on all textareas, unfocusing it. You can place this code where you want all textareas to be deselected.

```
$('textarea').bind('click', function() {
  $(this).select();
});
```

This will add a click event to all textareas, selecting all text when clicked.